# word for categories of units

Tags: single-word-requests

Let's say I'm trying to measure some variable, like GDP. The unit I'm measuring this in is dollars, and the type of unit is currency. Is there a word to describe things like "currency" in this scenario?

As another example, a variable could be stomach size, the unit is kilograms, and the thing I'm trying to describe is "weight"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least in physics and similar disciplines, I believe the term is **quanity**. An example from [Wikipaedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_quantity), in the entry on *Physical quantity*:

> ...
>   *Subscripts and indices of physical **quantity***
>   ...
>
> Name reference: The **quantity** has a subscripted or superscripted
>   single letter, a number of letters, or an entire word, to specify what
>   concept or entity they refer to, and tend to be written in upright
>   roman typeface rather than italic while the **quantity** is in italic.
>   For instance *E*<sub>k</sub> or *E*<sub>kinetic</sub> is usually used
>   to denote kinetic energy and *E*<sub>p</sub> or
>   *E*<sub>potential</sub> is usually used to denote potential energy.